# SQOOP import related query

Tags: mysql, shell, hadoop, sqoop

I have been facing issues while importing tables from RDBMS through SQOOP, I am executing the command with the following syntax:

```
sqoop import  --connect jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>:<port>;username=xxx;password=xxx;database=xxx --table xxx --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table xxxx
```

When I am executing it through command line, its working fine, but when I am trying to execute through shell script, it is throwing the following error:

> "error tool.basesqooptool got error creating database manager"

I have tried various permutation combination, still not working

I used `--username`  `--password` , then moved the db name right adjecent to the port number, I used `--driver`. But nothing is working.

I have checked similar discussions at SO, but none of them is working for me. `$SQOOP_HOME/lib` has the required librariy. The ownership and group ownership corresponds to `root:root`. The "user" has only `read` permission though, and I notice that in the same path, there are many other libraries, and the "user" has `rw` permission. Still I believe that since the command is working through CLI, there should be no issues executing from the script. I do not want to play with the permission, as its a very restricted environment, I want to keep that as last option.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to double-quote your JDBC URL

Answer (score 0):

When you are overwriting to the same table many times this will occur.

Use the below Sqoop command and see

**sqoop import -libjars** /var/lib/sqoop/ojdbc6.jar **--connect** 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname/service_name' **--username** user **-password** password **-m 1 --hive-overwrite --hive-import** **--hive-database** database_name **--hive-table** table_nmae **--target-dir** '/user/hive/warehouse/databasename.db/tablename' **--query** "select * from source_database.source_tablename **WHERE 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS**"

if it still gives you the same error, change the target-dir to some other hdfs location (ex: /temp/test/table_name)

If it reflects any error post the error, I can help you better.